# What is the difference between trainer.predict() and trainer.test() in PyTorch Lightning?

Tags: pytorch-lightning

I am trying to evaluate the accuracy of a model on a dataset in two different way. The first is `trainer.test()`, which returns the accuracy metrics, and the other one is `trainer.predict()`, which returns the predicted labels that can be used to calculate the accuracy with `accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)`. I do not know why but the two accuracies do not match.

Thank you for your help.